# How can I persist a perspective with public Eclipse 3 APIs?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Is there any way to programmatically persist an Eclipse 3 perspective using any of the public APIs? The persistence needs to be explicit, not implicit for example like the persistence which happens at shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=115808 there is no API to explicitly persist a perspective.

It seems that there aren't any plans either to provide such API.